# Why do you have to 'extend activity' in Android development?

Tags: android

When you create a new class, why must you always say for example:

```
class Main extends Activity { ... }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't. When you create a new `Activity`, it must extends `Activity`, but you may create any other class as well.

Extending `Activity` gives you the ready-made UI and resources management and allows the zigote to instantiate you as a GUI application.